# How do I shift main domain root to subfolder and prevent access to addon domains from main domain at the same time?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, shared-hosting

Once more I turn to SO when I am at my wits end. A client of mine is running three separate websites on a single hosting plan.
What I need to do is shift the main domain contents to a sub-folder and link the main domain to it so that

```
maindomain.com/
```

actually gets linked to

```
/maindomain/
```

This i got working with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?maindomain.com/$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maindomain/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /maindomain/$1  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?maindomain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ maindomain/index.html [L]
```

The Second part is the problem. I now need prevent addon domains domainA and domainB from being accessed from the main domain.To make matters more complicated, domainA is running cakePHP and domainB is running a custom framework which is totally dependent on its .htaccess

the domains lie in sub-folders of webroot as

```
/domainA/
```

and

```
/domainB/
```

I tried the following but it didn't prevent access to the add-on domains.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?maindomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/domainA/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/domainB/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=404]
```

I could really use some insight on what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule as **very first rule in both `/domainA/.htaccess` and `/domainB/.htaccess` files**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: just chaged the last line to
    RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
and it works like a charm! Thanks.