# Redirect every link in php application

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have made a php web application which uses links like :

> ```
> <a href="/asset/image.ext">Link</a>
>
> ... onClick="window.location.href='/asset/image.ext'" ...
>
> <? header("Location: /login"); ?>
>
> etc.
> ```

As you might have noticed, almost EVERY link starts with `/`.
Many links are rewritten in `.htaccess` like this :

> ```
> Options All -Indexes
> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteRule ^login/error_418$ assets/common/login.php?&error [L]
> RewriteRule ^login$ assets/common/login.php [L]
>
> RewriteRule ^settings/change-profile-picture$ index.php?page=settings&command=profilePicture [L]
> RewriteRule ^settings/change-password/error-requirements$ index.php?page=settings&command=password&error=requirements [L]
> RewriteRule ^settings/change-password/error-missmatch$ index.php?page=settings&command=password&error=missmatch [L]
> RewriteRule ^settings/change-password/error-418$ index.php?page=settings&command=password&error=418 [L]
>
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^(.+)/grades$ index.php?page=grades&course=$1 [L]
> ```

Now I need to move it on a web server where it will `NOT` be in the `root direcotry` but in a folder...

How do I now redirect all the root links to that folder ?

Comment: You should be editing the `httpd.conf` file and modifying the `vhost` entry to change the `DocumentRoot` if you have access.

Comment: This post might help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854352/how-do-i-shift-main-domain-root-to-subfolder-and-prevent-access-to-addon-domains

Comment: @ohgodwhy I have no access to the httpd.conf file as it is not my own server

Comment: The core question is: why are you no longer in the root directory? Is there another application in the root itself? Because if so, you're a truly screwed victim of 'naive web development' for assuming you always run in the root path...

Comment: @niels I know that it was a mistake... And now I'm trying to fix it without rewriting every single link

Comment: Well like I said, it's fixable (as @anubhava demonstrates) if you will still be the only website on the server, but if not - you're in for a total mess of conflicts, and patching every link in the code is probably faster than trying to cover it with workarounds.

Comment: The only viable other option is a `mod_proxy` hack, which would allow you to 'mount' an entire site in a subpath, but since you don't have access to the server's config files I won't need to bother explaining that route.

Answer (score 0):

First place your existing rule in `/folder/.htaccess` like this:

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /folder/

RewriteRule ^login/error_418$ assets/common/login.php?&error [L]
RewriteRule ^login$ assets/common/login.php [L]

RewriteRule ^settings/change-profile-picture$ index.php?page=settings&command=profilePicture [L]
RewriteRule ^settings/change-password/error-requirements$ index.php?page=settings&command=password&error=requirements [L]
RewriteRule ^settings/change-password/error-missmatch$ index.php?page=settings&command=password&error=missmatch [L]
RewriteRule ^settings/change-password/error-418$ index.php?page=settings&command=password&error=418 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/grades$ index.php?page=grades&course=$1 [L]
```

Then create a rule in root .htaccess as this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^((?!folder/).*)$ folder/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: This answer is only valid if there is no other application on the server.

Comment: I guess that is obvious by OP's use of `<? header("Location: /login"); ?>`

Comment: Why? That is entirely valid if you (naively) assume you will always be running in the root folder. If another site with dynamic URLs is in the root in the new situation, he's totally and thoroughly screwed because 90+% chance that it will need the `/login` path itself.

Comment: That is true if that is the case then it is indeed bad assumption on OP's part.